# Firebase auth with SMS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I have this code:

```
var applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': (response) => { 
    console.log('RECAPTCHA HECHO');
    }
});
var provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
provider.verifyPhoneNumber('+34'+this.phone, applicationVerifier)
.then((verificationId) => {
    this.verificationId = verificationId;
    console.log("Funciona", verificationId);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error);
});
```

But allways I get the same error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).

I'm trying to sing in with phone number. I'm using nuxtJS